# Ruby string to array conversion

Tags: ruby

I have a string that is URL encoded:

```
a = "%5B%22552A8619-6ECA-4A95-A798-C1E2CE75BFFF%22%2C%2264c19b5b2d0257ddb382dbd3660de3fd%22%2C%22share%22%5D"
```

If I URL decode this string then it will look like:

```
"[\"552A8619-6ECA-4A95-A798-C1E2CE75BFFF\",\"64c19b5b2d0257ddb382dbd3660de3fd\",\"share\"]"
```

From this string I want to get this array:

```
["552A8619-6ECA-4A95-A798-C1E2CE75BFFF","64c19b5b2d0257ddb382dbd3660de3fd","share"]
```

How to do that without nasty string replacements?

Comment: Where are you getting the string? Is it the result of some sort of a HTTP request? And, could that string be actually a JSON string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
the_given_string.scan(/"(.*?)"/).flatten
```

Comment: While all other answers were correct, but I selected this because it looks very terse and works. By the way, I dont require to pass argument `1` in flatten

Comment: @JVK I had thought that providing the maximum depth to `flatten` improves the performance, but lost confidence. I just asked a question  about it.

Answer (score 3):

The string is an array encoded using JSON:

```
require 'cgi'
require 'json'

a = "%5B%22552A8619-6ECA-4A95-A798-C1E2CE75BFFF%22%2C%2264c19b5b2d0257ddb382dbd3660de3fd%22%2C%22share%22%5D"

JSON[CGI::unescape(a)]

[
    [0] "552A8619-6ECA-4A95-A798-C1E2CE75BFFF",
    [1] "64c19b5b2d0257ddb382dbd3660de3fd",
    [2] "share"
]
```

`JSON[CGI::unescape(a)].last` will return `"share"`, putting you home free.

[`CGI::escape`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-unescape) is used to remove the encoding, which turns it back to a "normal" JSON-encoded array.

[`JSON[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-c-5B-5D) (AKA [`JSON.parse`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse)) converts it from the JSON notation back to a Ruby array.

Answer (score 2):

You could delete characters and split, or evaluate it:

```
"[\"A798-C1E2CE75BFFF\",\"643fd\",\"share\"]".delete('\"[]').split(',')
# => ["A798-C1E2CE75BFFF", "643fd", "share"]

eval "[\"A798-C1E2CE75BFFF\",\"643fd\",\"share\"]"
# => ["A798-C1E2CE75BFFF", "643fd", "share"]
```

Comment: Thank you. But `eval` being crazy, I am hesitant to use it. First answer works.

Answer (score 1):

You could `eval` the string:

```
require 'cgi'
a = "%5B%22552A8619-6ECA-4A95-A798-C1E2CE75BFFF%22%2C%2264c19b5b2d0257ddb382dbd3660de3fd%22%2C%22share%22%5D"
x = eval( CGI.unescape(a))
p x #["552A8619-6ECA-4A95-A798-C1E2CE75BFFF", "64c19b5b2d0257ddb382dbd3660de3fd", "share"]
```

But eval is evil.

You could use , what you call *nasty string replacement*:

```
p CGI.unescape(a).gsub(/\A\["|"\]\Z/,'').split(/","/)
```

Or you could try `JSON`:

```
require 'cgi'
require 'json'
a = "%5B%22552A8619-6ECA-4A95-A798-C1E2CE75BFFF%22%2C%2264c19b5b2d0257ddb382dbd3660de3fd%22%2C%22share%22%5D"
x = JSON.load( CGI.unescape(a))
```

Comment: Thank you. You have a very comprehensive answer :)